# Document keydown triggers button not working | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, keydown, enter

I need help with getting the keydown of Enter to trigger a button click. I have already coded some javascript so that when the user presses enter in the text boxes that different buttons are clicked, but I now want the 'You shall Pass!' button to be triggered when the user presses enter anywhere in the document(not a text box) so that a div will be created with their inputted text. Right now if you click the 'You shall pass!' button, it will work, but I want this button to be triggered even when the user presses Enter.
I have tried using:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    if(document.getElementById('buid')) {
       bu.click();
    }
}
}
```

but then when the user presses enter to trigger the 'Validate Inputs' button, the div just appears and no 'You shall Pass!' appears, thus it just triggers that button without it appearing. The above code is not in the below code snippet. How do I solve this using Vanilla JS? 
P.S. 'bu' is the variable of the 'You shall Pass!' button and 'buid' is the id of that button.

```js
var inputg = document.getElementById("inputtext");
var b = document.getElementById('button');
inputg.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
 b.click();
}
};

inputg.addEventListener("input", noButton);

function noButton(){
if(inputg.value === ""){
 b.style.display = 'none';
}else{
 b.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
}

noButton();


b.addEventListener('click', function(){
addDiv();
});


function addDiv(){
b.parentNode.removeChild(b);
var inputv = document.getElementById("inputtext").value;
var n = document.createElement("input");
n.type = "number";
n.placeholder = "Enter your Age";
var nv = n.value;
document.getElementById("bodydiv").appendChild(n);
n.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
 but.click();
}
};
var but = document.createElement("button");
but.innerHTML = "Validate Inputs";
document.getElementById("bodydiv").appendChild(but);
inputg.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
 but.click();
}
};
var bu = document.createElement("button");
bu.id = "buid";
bu.innerHTML= "You shall Pass!";
document.getElementById("bodydiv").appendChild(bu);
bu.style.display = 'none';
but.addEventListener('click', function(){
if(n.value<=0 || inputg.value === ""){
alert("Invalid Age or Name, You shall not pass!");
}else{
inputg.disabled = true;
n.disabled = true;
but.style.display = 'none';
bu.style.display = 'inline';
}
});
bu.addEventListener('click', function(){
inputg.disabled = false;
n.disabled = false;
bu.style.display = 'none';
but.style.display = 'inline-block';
var inputvs = document.getElementById("inputtext").value;
var ns = n.value;
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = "My name is " + inputg.value + "<br />" + "And I am " + n.value + " years old";
d.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("bodydiv").appendChild(d);
n.value = "";
inputg.value = "";
});

if((bu.style.display = 'none')){
inputg.disabled = false;
n.disabled = false;
}
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter LOTR name">
  <button id="button">GO!
  </button>
  <div id="bodydiv">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try different method for listen the whole `div` or page.

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        b.click();
    }
});
```

Also

```
$('body').on('keydown', function() {
     if(event.keyCode == 13){
        b.click();
    }
});
```

And

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        b.click();
    }
}):
```

Comment: This causes a div to appear every time the user presses enter. I only want the div to appear when the user presses enter when the 'You shall pass!' button is displayed in the DOM. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can handle this with if condition check that 'You shall pass' display is visible and enter is pressed.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to be working. When I used the if statement with your code, the 'you shall pass' button is triggered when the 'Validate Inputs' button is triggered. So the div appears before it's supposed to.